# Trying to simplify an expression for an induction proof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, factorial

I got it down to $(k+2)!-1 + (k+1)((k+1)!)$ I am trying to get it to $(k+2)!-1$ but I guess I do not understand factorials enough to simplify this. I am also assuming I am doing the induction correctly so far.

prove: that $\sum_{i=1}^n (i)(i!) = (n+1)!-1$ for all positive integers n greater than or equal to 1.

Base Case:

LHS = $\sum_{i=1}^1 (1)(1!) = 1$ RHS= $(1+1)!-1 = 1$

LHS = RHS base case holds

Inductive Hypothesis: n = k for arbitrary integer.

Assume $\sum_{i =1}^{k} (i)(i!) = (k+1)!-1$

IS: Show $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(i)(i!) = (k+2)!-1$

Proof:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (i)(i!) = \sum_{i=1}^k (i)(i!) + (k+1)$

$ = \sum_{i=1}^k (i)(i!) + (k+1)(k+1)!$

$= (k+2)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)!$

EDIT: added work so far
EDIT: cleaned parenthesis up

Comment: Hmm is false... + or - (k+1)...?

Comment: I actually made a type I mean i am trying to get it to $(k+2)!-1$ but I am not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show us the steps how you got to that formula, and what the problem is? It is unclear from the limited information given where an error was made.

Comment: well unless (k+1)((k+1)!)=0 (it doesn't), an error must have been made earlier

Comment: @Jude If you put a negative sign before $(k+1)(k+1)!$, your expression would be correct. That is, $(k+2)! - 1 - (k+1)(k+1)! = (k+1)! - 1$ is correct.

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman I am editing to add my work so far 1sec

Comment: And I just realized my exact question is on the side wow.

Comment: Your question is totally false. Please fix the problem

Comment: The first step of your proof should read $$\sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} i \cdot i! = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} i \cdot i! + (k + 1)(k + 1)!$$  The induction hypothesis allows you to substitute $(k + 1)! - 1$ for $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} i \cdot i!$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig would I be able to simplify $(k+1)!-1 $ into $k!$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your induction hypothesis is 
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{i = 1}^{k} i \cdot i! = (k + 1)! - 1}$$
You set up the induction step incorrectly.  Substituting $k + 1$ for $i$ in the expression $i \cdot i!$ yields $(k + 1)(k + 1)!$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} i \cdot i! & = \color{blue}{\sum_{i = 1}^{k} i \cdot i!} + (k + 1)(k + 1)! && \text{by definition}\\
& = \color{blue}{(k + 1)! - 1} + (k + 1)(k + 1)! && \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
& = (1 + k + 1)(k + 1)! - 1 && \text{factor}\\
& = (k + 2)(k + 1)! - 1\\
& = (k + 2)! - 1
\end{align*}

Comment: I am actually a bit confused on what/how you factored out the factorial

Comment: Observe that \begin{align*}(k + 1)! - 1 + (k + 1)(k + 1)! & = \color{green}{1} \cdot (k + 1)!  + \color{green}{(k + 1)}(k + 1)! - 1\\ & = \color{green}{(1 + k + 1)}(k + 1)! - 1\end{align*}